# kubernetes-client watch till all pods are up

Tags: java, kubernetes

I want to poll pod status in the namespace till all pod are up, I am using kubernetes-client library to check it. What should be the exit condition when all pods are up. I need to close watch when all pods are up but it keeps polling till the timeout given while creating watch object

```
 String file = "C:\\Project\\config.yaml";
        String content = readFromFile(file);
        InputStream kubeConfigStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
 ApiClient client = getApiClient(kubeConfigStream);
        Configuration.setDefaultApiClient(client);
        // infinite timeout
        OkHttpClient httpClient =
                client.getHttpClient().newBuilder().readTimeout(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
        client.setHttpClient(httpClient);
        Configuration.setDefaultApiClient(client);
        CoreV1Api api = new CoreV1Api();
        String namespace = "default";

 @Cleanup
        Watch<V1Pod> watch = Watch.createWatch(
                client,
                api.listNamespacedPodCall(namespace, null, true, null,
                        null, null, 20, null, null, 190, Boolean.TRUE, null),
                new TypeToken<Watch.Response<V1Pod>>() {
                }.getType());

for (Watch.Response<V1Pod> item : watch) {
    V1PodStatus podStatus = item.object.getStatus();
    String name = item.object.getMetadata().getName();
    String status = podStatus.getPhase();
   
    System.out.printf("NAME:" +name+"\t status"+status);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get all pods details using below function

```
V1PodList listNamespacePod =
                    coreV1Api.listNamespacedPod(
                            namespace,
                            null,
                            null,
                            null,
                            null,
                            null,
                            Integer.MAX_VALUE,
                            null,
                            null,
                            40,
                            Boolean.FALSE);
```

After that update live updated using watch

```
 switch (eventType) {
                        case "ADDED":
                        case "MODIFIED":
                            checkContainerStatus(v1PodResponse, podName, namespacePods);
                            break;
                        case "DELETED":
                            namespacePods.remove(podName);
                            break;
                        case "FAILED":
                            namespacePods.put(podName, eventType);
                            break;
                        default:

                    }
```